# How does one complete "over-qualified employee" missions in Uplink?

Tags: uplink

I've always been interested in Uplink, so I bought it earlier this week. But now I'm stuck on one of the missions that has been appearing since I reached the "Confident" rank: it's asking me to prove that an employee is over-qualified by changing his academic record. Specifically: "We feel that this employee scored slightly too highly at his degree. Give him a 3rd class replacement."

I break into the academic database, look up the employee, and find that he has three classes, so I change the grade letter on the third class from a D to an F, commit, and disconnect. But when I reply to the mission request asking for money, they tell me that I haven't changed anything yet.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding here? How does one fulfill the goal of this mission?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to change the class in the `Other Qualifications` section.

For example, you have to change `Philosophy, Class 1` to `Philosophy, Class 3`, then save.

Answer (score 3):

> [Well if you look at the record the guy has a degree with "class 1" after it, aka a 1st class degree.  All you need to do is change the 1 to a 3](http://forums.introversion.co.uk/uplink/viewtopic.php?p=350162).